# TensorFlow REST Frontend but not TensorFlow Serving

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to deploy a simple TensorFlow model and run it in REST service like Flask.
Did not find so far good example on github or here.

I am not ready to use TF Serving as suggested in other posts, it is perfect solution for Google but it overkill for my tasks with gRPC, bazel, C++ coding, protobuf...

Comment: to narrow question just wanting a working example of  returning results in Flask after saver loads model

Comment: 22 people did not think that it is too broad

Comment: Hello! I can see how this would be a useful question! However, it would be very difficult to supply code here (since the question is really quite broad) and there are many ways to make this happen. If you shared with us specific code that you wrote to accomplish this, then we would be able to help debug that code. There's a related site, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, which may be able to help you come up with a design. Best of luck!

Comment: This is too broad according to the site's rules but I voted to reopen anyway. You can find a lot of tutorials on Flask, just put the work in and you'll have a solution.

Comment: At the time of asking this question there was no tutorial like https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/29/scalable-keras-deep-learning-rest-api/ . However, if anyone would try to implement production ready solution, it needs to consider GPU memory limitation,thread concurrency, model optimization and immutablity etc. Actually there is no simple and easy way for it, but more products delivered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. Purely, using tensorflow is not very flexible, however relatively straightforward. The downside of this approach is that you have to rebuild the graph and initialize variables in the code where you restore the model. There is a way shown in [tensorflow skflow/contrib learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn) which is more elegant, however this doesn't seem to be functional at the moment and the documentation is out of date.

I put a short example together on github [here](https://github.com/benman1/tensorflow_flask) that shows how you would named GET or POST parameters to a flask REST-deployed tensorflow model.

The main code is then in a function that takes a dictionary based on the POST/GET data:

```
@app.route('/model', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@parse_postget
def apply_model(d):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.Session() as session:
        n = 1
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n], name='x')
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n], name='y')
        m = tf.Variable([1.0], name='m')
        b = tf.Variable([1.0], name='b')
        y = tf.add(tf.mul(m, x), b) # fit y_i = m * x_i + b
        y_act = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n], name='y_')
        error = tf.sqrt((y - y_act) * (y - y_act))
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error)

        feed_dict = {x: np.array([float(d['x_in'])]), y_act: np.array([float(d['y_star'])])}
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(session, 'linear.chk')
        y_i, _, _ = session.run([y, m, b], feed_dict)
    return jsonify(output=float(y_i))
```

Answer (score 3):

This [github project](https://github.com/sugyan/tensorflow-mnist/blob/master/main.py) shows a working example of restoring a model checkpoint and using Flask.

```
@app.route('/api/mnist', methods=['POST'])
def mnist():
    input = ((255 - np.array(request.json, dtype=np.uint8)) / 255.0).reshape(1, 784)
    output1 = simple(input)
    output2 = convolutional(input)
    return jsonify(results=[output1, output2])
```

The online [demo](https://tensorflow-mnist.herokuapp.com/) seems pretty quick.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like to put much code with data/model processing in flask restful file. I usually have tf model class and so on separately.  *i.e.* it could be something like this:

```
# model init, loading data
cifar10_recognizer = Cifar10_Recognizer()
cifar10_recognizer.load('data/c10_model.ckpt')

@app.route('/tf/api/v1/SomePath', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    X = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'photo' in request.files:
            # place for uploading process workaround, obtaining input for tf
            X = generate_X_c10(f)

        if len(X) != 0:
            # designing desired result here
            answer = np.squeeze(cifar10_recognizer.predict(X))
            top3 = (-answer).argsort()[:3]
            res = ([cifar10_labels[i] for i in top3], [answer[i] for i in top3])

            # you can simply print this to console
            # return 'Prediction answer: {}'.format(res)

            # or generate some html with result
            return fk.render_template('demos/c10_show_result.html',
                                      name=file,
                                      result=res)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # in html I have simple form to upload img file
        return fk.render_template('demos/c10_classifier.html')
```

cifar10_recognizer.predict(X) is simple func, that runs prediction operation in tf session:

```
    def predict(self, image):
        logits = self.sess.run(self.model, feed_dict={self.input: image})
        return logits
```

p.s. saving/restoring the model from a file is an extremely long process, try to avoid this while serving post/get requests