# Importing Tensorflow Session Bundle in Python

Tags: tensorflow

How do you import from inside Python a Tensorflow session bundle? The docs explain [exporting from Python](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle#exporting-python-code) and [importing in C++](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle#importing-c-code).

UPDATE:
I found the following:

1. [`load_session_bundle_from_path`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c856366b739850a9f4b0bf1469de7f052619042b/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/session_bundle.py#L35)
2. [`python.saved_model.loader.load`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c856366b739850a9f4b0bf1469de7f052619042b/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader.py#L119)

Answer (score 1):

SessionBundle consists of a checkpoint and a MetaGraph definition that's needed for serving (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle)). Since TensorFlow Serving is in C++, I don't think you will find any Python examples).

However, if you are using Python, you don't actually need this MetaGraph definition, you can just start a new session and restore from the checkpoint file, and subsequently do the inferences from this new session. You can find some good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935428/tensorflow-rest-frontend-but-not-tensorflow-serving).

Comment: Won't I need the `MetaGraph` definition in order to restore the computation graph (assuming I don't have access to / want to re-run the Python code that was originally run to create the graph)?

Comment: Apparently, I restored the metagraph from the checkpoint-file, using 'tf.train.import_meta_graph()'. [here](https://gist.github.com/Fematich/80808454d05f9822517bd355962db755) you can find some pseudo-code from my project to see how you can restore from this checkpoint file, and the official TF documentation is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html).

Comment: Okay, that is what I am doing now. Since I used the `Exporter`, the names of the input and output nodes are a stored in a collection that seems to require a little more work to parse out.

Comment: Did you get it to work? Using [tf.all_variables()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#all_variables) and [tf.get_collection()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.get_collection) should help for your search of the correct names.